Best way to reach Mokra Gora and the Tara National Park from Belgrade
I am trying to figure out what's the best way to reach Mokra Gora and the Tara National Park from Belgrade.
I see there are trains running from Belgrade to Užice but I am worried getting a taxi from there to Mokra Gora may be difficult. Am I right ?
I see there are no buses either reaching Mokra Gora.
Is there a rental car company that allows to rent a car in Belgrade and drop it off in Mokra Gora paying a one way fee ?
Thank you.
